# Using DistributedCached in cluster mode

Tags: hadoop

I have a object:

```
class Cache {
    Map<K,V> map;
}
```

I used DistributedCache to specify a URI contains this object, then in the setup() function in each map task, I loaded this Cache object for processing.In particular, used Cache object to store some value in each map task.

My question is that the map's content in each datanode will be different with each others when we run hadoop in cluster mode. Is it right? Because when I developed in local mode, the map's content contains the result for whole dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The data saved on the DNs will be of same format and the mapper will process the file of the same format. In the driver code you have to define the input and format types.In this case the context will be same.The map context will be same if a map task will run on any number of DNs.

Now in the distributed cache you will add the files using DistributedCache API. And in the setup method you will check the file which you wants to process among the array of Path object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I mean here is that the map'p content will be different or not? Ex: node 1 contains A,B,C, node 2 contains D, E, F... then the cache file in node 1 contain (A,B,C) and cache file in node 2 (D,E,F)?

Comment: If you are writing Map Reduce Applications, where you want some files to be shared across all nodes in Hadoop Cluster. It can be simple properties file or can be executable jar file.

Hadoop Map Reduce Project provides us this facility with something called as DistributedCache.
This Distributed Cache is configured with Job Configuration, What it does is, it provides read only data to all machine on the cluster.